# Error Fatal utilizando un if con equals en la condicion

Tags: java, android-studio

Estaba haciendo un programa en android en donde utilizo una condicional if para detectar si encuentra o no un objeto. Si encuentra al objeto el programa funciona sin inconvenientes y resuelve lo que necesito. Sino se cumple la condición en ves de no hacer nada se me rompe el programa dando un error fatal en la consola de logcat. No puedo entender cual es el error ya que estoy pidiendo algo muy simple y no tiene complejidad. les dejo un fragmento del codigo y el mensaje de error de la consola.
Muchas Gracias

```
    boolean encuentra = false;

    String correo=mail.getText().toString().trim();
    String clave=key.getText().toString().trim();

    int i=0;

    while(i<=listaUsuarios.size() && !encuentra)
    {

        if(((listaUsuarios.get(i).getClave()).equals(clave)) && ((listaUsuarios.get(i).getEmail()).equals(correo)))
        {
            encuentra = true;
        }
        
        i++;
    }

    if(encuentra)
    {
        this.iniciar();
    }
    else
    {
        valida.setText("USUARIO INEXISTENTE");
        valida.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                  Process: com.example.final_laum_2023, PID: 7977                                                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick                                                                                                       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:473)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7659)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7636)
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30156)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7659) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7636) 
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30156) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
at java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:434)
at com.example.final_laum_2023.MainActivity.iniciarSesion(MainActivity.java:77)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7659) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7636) 
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30156) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

---

Bien, quitando el = no entra en el ciclo while, parece ser que  no me esta cargando los objetos a la lista. Ahora no entiendo el porque. Si hago un listaUsuario.size() me devuelve 0 asi que supongo que no me los esta cargando. El objeto si me lo crea por que haciendo un Log.d me devuelve atributos del mismo.

```
EditText mail,key;
TextView valida;
ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuarios = new ArrayList();

@SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.setTitle("Principal");

    valida=findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    valida.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mail=findViewById(R.id.idEmail);
    key=findViewById(R.id.idContraseña);


    FirebaseFirestore usuarios = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    usuarios.collection("users")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Usuario u = new Usuario(document.getString("apellido"),document.getString("dni"),document.getString("email"),document.getString("nombre"),document.getString("password"));
                            listaUsuarios.add(u);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error al cargar los usuarios", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}

public void iniciarSesion(View v){

    boolean encuentra = false;

    String correo=mail.getText().toString().trim();
    String clave=key.getText().toString().trim();

    int i=0;

    while(i<listaUsuarios.size() && !encuentra)
    {

        if(((listaUsuarios.get(i).getClave()).equals(clave)) && ((listaUsuarios.get(i).getEmail()).equals(correo)))
        {
            encuentra = true;
        }
        
        i++;
    }

    if(encuentra)
    {
        this.iniciar();
    }
    else
    {
        valida.setText("USUARIO INEXISTENTE");
        valida.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Comment: El error está claro, estás intentando acceder a la posición 1 de una lista con un solo elemento. El problema no es el equals del if sino el "=" en la condición del while. Quítalo, debería ser mientras i < listaUsuarios.size()

Comment: No me esta cargando los objetos a la lista si hago un Log.d("Largo de la Lista", listaUsuarios.size()) me devuelve 0 como valor. Por que motivo será?.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se indica aquí:

> Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds
> for length 1 at
> jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)

En este caso, deberías iterar únicamente si `listaUsuarios`  contiene elementos, pero la variable `encuentra` no debería ser usada para determinar iterar. Además, cuando encuentres la coincidencia, puedes terminar la iteración usando `break;`, realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
public void iniciarSesion(View v){

    boolean encuentra = false;

    String correo=mail.getText().toString().trim();
    String clave=key.getText().toString().trim();

    int i=0;

    //while(i<listaUsuarios.size() && !encuentra)
    while(i<listaUsuarios.size())
    {

        if(((listaUsuarios.get(i).getClave()).equals(clave)) && ((listaUsuarios.get(i).getEmail()).equals(correo)))
        {
            encuentra = true;
        break; //Termina iteración, ya que encuentra = true .
        }
        
        i++;
    }

    if(encuentra)
    {
        this.iniciar();
    }
    else
    {
        valida.setText("USUARIO INEXISTENTE");
        valida.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```